# Wordpress Year archive not working

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I have a strange issue that is driving me crazy, I am hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

This started happening recently, but I can't put my finger on exactly when.

This is my post archive page: http://test.aclighting.com/news/ and it's using home.php. This looks ok until you click on a year archive link: http://test.aclighting.com/news/2010/, it should be using date.php.

The news doesn't change, its the same list as before. If I put the year in the querystring it does work: http://test.aclighting.com/news/?year=2010 but is still using home.php.

Oddly though, monthly archives do work: http://test.aclighting.com/news/2010/10/ and use the date.php template file.

I have tried with all plugins turned off, and have tried using Twenty Twelve theme, it doesn't make any difference. I have tried saving my permalink settings too.

The site is set to use a static front page, a page called Home as the home page, and a page called News for the news posts page.

Since this doesn't appear to be a theme issue or plugin issue I can only assume its a setting issue, but can't see what it is. Any suggestions?

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: To make this even weirder a page 2 of a year archive does work: http://test.aclighting.com/news/2014/page/2/

Comment: I have made some progress this morning, it might help others in similar situations.

My permalink structure is /news/%postname%/

My posts page was set to /news/

Once I had changed the slug of my posts page everything started to work again. What I don't understand is why it worked before. I don't know what changed.

Comment: Also, if I have /news/%postname%/ as my permalink structure, shouldn't archive.php be used if I browse to /news/?